# SOCKS vs. SSH local port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, socks

What's the difference between using SOCKS (SSH -D) and local port forwarding (SSH -L)

Comment: Also helpful: http://superuser.com/a/408032/102047

Comment: SOCKS is a full protocol where you need to talk to the proxy because it can do a lot.  Port forwarding is much more simple.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With `-L`, SSH forwards all connections to a fixed destination. When you connect to the local port, all data you send goes straight to the remote host which you specified in `-L`. This, obviously, requires you to know which host you want to forward connections to.

With `-D`, the destination is "dynamic" – after connecting to the local port, you have to use the [SOCKS proxy protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) to further connect to whatever remote host you want. This basically makes SSH a real proxy server, suitable for such activities as web browsing, where you cannot know in advance the destination.

Run `ssh -D 1080`, for example, and configure Firefox to use a SOCKS 5 proxy at `localhost:1080`.

Comment: I often use `ssh -D 8080 myhomecomputer` when I use my laptop on public wifi.

Comment: @EvanKrall Is the benefit of that approach the fact that all traffic (assuming applications are indeed using the SOCKS proxy) will be encrypted through your SSH connection (i.e. there will not be any _plain text_ network requests) ?  Also, how would one make sure all traffic is sent through the proxy?  Is there a recommended way to do this for all applications?

Comment: @blong: The recommended way would be to use an OS-wide VPN connection instead.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks @grawity .  I thought it might be something one could implement without a VPN client :)